# Как в Python watchdog получить имя модифицированного файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть простейший код watchdog для отслеживания изменений в папке, и он даже показывает файл, который был изменен, но как мне получить в отдельную переменную имя модифицированного файла?

Результат выдачи:
2022-11-30 11:35:41 - Moved file: from C:\Users\user\Desktop~WRD0453.tmp to C:\Users\user\Desktop\V1.docx

сам код:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
    #path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ! В event.src_path как раз лежит нужный файл!

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.path = path

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.path, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        # if event.is_directory:
        #     return None
        print(
            "[{}] noticed: [{}] on: [{}] ".format(
                time.asctime(), event.event_type, event.src_path
            )
        )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = Watcher('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\')
    w.run()
```